# associate function is not working in hasMany relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 ad having issues on saving through the hasMany relationship.

I have tables job and jobsite which has One-to-Many Relation i.e Each jobsite has one or many jobs

but when I am trying to add `job_job_site_id` in the job table using `associate()` it send me an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "job_site" of relation "job" does not exist
LINE 1: update "job" set "updated_at" = $1, "job_site" = $2 ...
^ (SQL: update "job" set "updated_at" = 2016-11-13 15:29:37, "job_site" = where "job_id" = 3)

SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "job_site" of relation "job" does not exist
LINE 1: update "job" set "updated_at" = $1, "job_site" = $2 ...
^
```

**Database structure:**

```
job (1st table)
– job_id
– job_name
– job_job_site_id
- created_at
- updated_at

job_site (2nd table)
– job_site_id
– job_site_name
- created_at
- updated_at
```

**Model Class Job:**

```
class Job extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job';
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_id';

    public function jobsite() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\JobSite', 'job_site', 'job_job_site_id', 'job_site_id');
    }
}
```

**Model Class JobSite:**

```
class JobSite extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job_site';
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_site_id';

    public function jobs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Job', 'job', 'job_job_site_id', 'job_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function jobsiteJobs($data)
{
    $jobsite = JobSite::find(3);
    $job_id = array(1,2,3);
    if (!empty($jobsite)) {
        foreach ($job_id as $id) {
            $job = Job::find($id);
            $job->jobsite()->associate($jobsite);
            $job->save();
        }
        return 'Added';
    }   
    else {
        return 'Not found';
    }
}
```

*Do I have my relationship defined incorrectly here?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your have defined relationships incorrectly. The correct version is following:

Model Class Job:

```
class Job extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job';
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_id';

    public function jobsite() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\JobSite', 'job_job_site_id', 'job_site_id');
    }
}
```

Model Class JobSite:

```
class JobSite extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job_site';
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_site_id';

    public function jobs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Job', 'job_job_site_id', 'job_site_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue after implementing your answer

Comment: Is the error same or it's different from the previous one?

Comment: I am not sure why it's giving the same error. The above error shows `column "job_site" of relation "job" does not exist` which was true because your relation FK was not defined correctly. You can test it by running this command in your controller `Job::find(1)->jobsite`.

Comment: I am trying to hit `$jobsite = Job::find(5)->jobsite()->job_site_id; ``dd($jobsite);` but it shows me this error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$job_site_id`

Comment: Don't use `()` parenthesis, just use `Job::find(1)->jobsite` or `Job::find(1)->jobsite-> job_site_id`. And let me know the result.

Comment: it showing this error: `SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column job_site.job_job_site_id does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "job_site" where "job_site"."job_job_s...`

Comment: also this error: `SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column job_site.job_job_site_id does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "job_site" where "job_site"."job_job_s...
^ (SQL: select * from "job_site" where "job_site"."job_job_site_id" is null limit 1)`